# Initializing history for redux-undo isn't populating past or future

Tags: reactjs, redux, undo-redo

I am having an issue initializing the history for an undoable reducer using `redux-undo`. [These are the directions I followed.](https://github.com/omnidan/redux-undo#initial-state-and-history) The `present` state is loaded, but the `past` and `future` states are not loaded. I'm hosting the code here, https://murmuring-shelf-40601.herokuapp.com I've added a logger to the middleware so if you open the console you'll see undo/redu history.

Here is my store. I've wrapped it in a promise because I'm fetching the history from a service, but I've hardcoded the initial history to the initialHistory object for testing. The code hosted on herokuapp.com is fetching live data.

```
import { get } from 'axios'
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux'
import { createLogger } from "redux-logger";
import thunk from "redux-thunk"
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import Promise from 'promise';
import UndoableNoteList from '../reducers/UndoableNoteList/UndoableNoteList'

var store = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    get("/server/load-notes").catch((response)=> {
        const initialHistory = {
            "UndoableNoteList": {
                "present": {
                    "list": [
                        {
                            "id": "f5230212-8a46-4a48-91c1-5fadd4e4ae5e",
                            "text": "123123123123123123213"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "bd4fe681-5071-4dd8-99e8-f46825eee866",
                            "text": "Jdk123123123123123123123sjdmd"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "past": [
                    {
                        "list": [
                            {
                                "id": "c60dc097-00ea-4dfa-9532-de44b25b1a7a",
                                "text": "Eggs"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "f61997bc-c8d7-46d7-836f-44af50a1a70d",
                                "text": "Milk"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "ab932fae-8588-4b20-a6c4-620c6a4345f7",
                                "text": "Cheese"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "list": [
                            {
                                "id": "f5230212-8a46-4a48-91c1-5fadd4e4ae5e",
                                "text": "Hhhfg"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "bd4fe681-5071-4dd8-99e8-f46825eee866",
                                "text": "Jdksjdmd"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "future": []
            }
        };
        const reducer = combineReducers({UndoableNoteList: UndoableNoteList});
        const middleware = applyMiddleware(thunk, createLogger());
        const store = createStore(reducer, initialHistory, middleware);
        resolve(store);
    });
});

export default store
```

Here's my undoable reducer.

Update - There are a few issues with this reducer. Don't use it as a reference.

```
import undoable from 'redux-undo'
import {loadNotesComplete} from '../../actions/LoadNotesComplete'
import {loadNotesSuccess} from '../../actions/LoadNotesSuccess'
import {loadNotesFailure} from '../../actions/LoadNotesFailure'

import {saveNotesWaiting} from '../../actions/SaveNotesWaiting'
import {saveNotesPost} from '../../actions/SaveNotesPost'
import {saveNotesSuccess} from '../../actions/SaveNotesSuccess'
import {saveNotesFailure} from '../../actions/SaveNotesFailure'

import store from '../../store/Store'

const NoteList = (state = {}, action = {}) => {
    if (action.type === "ADD_NOTE") {
        state.currentNoteSaveState = "ADD_NOTE";
        action.payload.then((note)=> {
            state.list = state.list.concat(note);
            store.then((store)=> {
                store.dispatch(saveNotesWaiting(store.getState()));
            });
        });
    } else if (action.type === "REMOVE_NOTE") {
        state.currentNoteSaveState = "REMOVE_NOTE";
        action.payload.then((id)=> {
            state.list = state.list.filter(function (item) {
                return item.id !== id;
            });
            store.then((store)=> {
                store.dispatch(saveNotesWaiting(store.getState()));
            });
        });
    } else if (action.type === "LOAD_NOTES") {
        state.currentNoteSaveState = "LOAD_NOTES";
        action.payload.then((response)=> {
            response = {...response};
            store.then((store)=> {
                store.dispatch(loadNotesComplete(response));
            });
        }).catch((reject)=> {
            console.log("reject from axios promise");
            console.log(reject);
        });
    } else if (action.type === "LOAD_NOTES_COMPLETE") {
        state.currentNoteSaveState = "LOAD_NOTES_COMPLETE";
        action.payload.then((response)=> {
            if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
                store.then((store)=> {
                    store.dispatch(loadNotesSuccess(response.data.UndoableNoteList));
                });
            }
            else {
                console.log("loadNotesFailure(response)");
                store.then((store)=> {
                    store.dispatch(loadNotesFailure(response));
                });
            }
        });
    } else if (action.type === "LOAD_NOTES_SUCCESS") {
        //console.log("action.payload");
        //console.log(action.payload);
        //state.currentNoteSaveState = "LOAD_NOTES_SUCCESS";
        //state.list = action.payload.present.list;
    } else if (action.type === "LOAD_NOTES_FAILURE") {
        state.currentNoteSaveState = "LOAD_NOTES_FAILURE";
        console.log(action.payload);
    }
    else if (action.type === "SAVE_NOTES_WAITING") {
        state.currentNoteSaveState = "SAVE_NOTES_WAITING";
        action.payload.then((notes)=> {
            store.then((store)=>{
                store.dispatch(saveNotesPost(notes));
            });
        }).catch(()=> {
            console.log("canceling previous save");
        });
    } else if (action.type === "SAVE_NOTES_POST") {
        state.currentNoteSaveState = "SAVE_NOTES_POST";
        action.payload.then((response)=> {
            if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
                store.then((store)=>{
                    store.dispatch(saveNotesSuccess(response));
                });

            } else {
                store.then((store)=>{
                    store.dispatch(saveNotesFailure(response));
                });
            }
        });
    } else if (action.type === "SAVE_NOTES_SUCCESS") {
        state.currentNoteSaveState = "SAVE_NOTES_SUCCESS";
    } else if (action.type === "SAVE_NOTES_FAILURE") {
        state.currentNoteSaveState = "SAVE_NOTES_FAILURE";
    } else if (action.type === "UNDO") {
        state.currentNoteSaveState = "UNDO";
        action.payload.then(()=> {
            store.then((store)=>{
                store.dispatch(saveNotesWaiting(store.getState()));
            });

        });
    } else if (action.type === "REDO") {
        state.currentNoteSaveState = "REDO";
        action.payload.then(()=> {
            store.then((store)=> {
                store.dispatch(saveNotesWaiting(store.getState()));
            });
        });
    }
    console.log(action.type);
    console.log(state);
    state = {...state};
    return state;
};

const UndoableNoteList = undoable(NoteList, {
    filter: function filterActions(action, currentState, previousHistory) {
        return action.type === "ADD_NOTE" ||
            action.type === "REMOVE_NOTE";
    }
});
export default UndoableNoteList;
```

And here is the `index.js` where I setup the provider

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import Layout from './pages/Layout';
import './index.css';
import {Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory } from "react-router"
import Home from './pages/Home/Home';
import ListView from './pages/ListView/ListView'
import ListAdd from './pages/ListAdd/ListAdd'

import store from './store/Store'

store.then((store)=> {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Router history={hashHistory}>
                <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
                    <IndexRoute component={Home} name="Home"></IndexRoute>
                    <Route path="/view-notes" component={ListView} name="ViewNotes"></Route>
                    <Route path="/add-note" component={ListAdd} name="AddNote"></Route>
                </Route>
            </Router>
        </Provider>,
        document.getElementById('root')
    );
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I updated the `redux-undo` library from `0.6.1` to `1.0.0-beta7` and now the history is being populated correctly

Comment: Thank you for this. I've been trying for hours to find the right solution and stumbled across this post. Downgraded versions and it works perfectly!

Comment: @sidonaldson FYI I ran into other issues with the 1.0.0 beta. It would remove the first item in the `past` array when I loaded a state with both a `past` and `future`. I ended up removing the library and implementing my own undo/redo logic in the reducer. The redux docs do a good job explaining how to implement it.  http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ImplementingUndoHistory.html

Comment: @sissnob thanks! Luckily my usecase is extremely simple and it now works fine. I'll look out for that bug tho